# How to make React and Meteor fit together

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs

I don't know if it's more a **React** or **Meteor** concern, maybe both, but I am currently building a web app with these two frameworks and I am facing a programmer issue. I am not a Javascript developer but a Java developer (I use daily GWT), so maybe I made some rookie mistakes.

My app keeps growing and I have more and more React components, about twenty or so. Now that I have a view that is fine, I have added some functionalities to my components but it turns up I add more and more logic in the react components which is, I believe, against MVC principles.

However, I don't know how to move the logic in "Meteor controller components". Right now, I use Meteor for its model and that's just about all. I saw many times this [Pete Hunt's talk](https://www.meteor.com/blog/2014/02/14/pete-hunt-talks-facebook-react) and how he built his application but it has only one 'simple' component.

In fact, without React, the view would be in html files, defined with templates. The controller would be in js files and the logic will appear to be there. I can clearly see the **split between** the **view** and the **controller**.

Html file (from leaderboard example):

```
<template name="leaderboard">
  ...
</template>

<template name="player">
  <div class="player {{selected}}">
    ...
  </div>
</template>
```

Javascript file (from leaderboard example):

```
...     
Template.leaderboard.players = function () {
     return Players.find({}, {sort: {score: -1, name: 1}});
 };

 Template.leaderboard.selected_name = function () {
     var player = Players.findOne(Session.get("selected_player"));
     return player && player.name;
 };
...
```

Since React is javascript, it's really easy and tempting to put all we want in React components.

I am aware of these frameworks are relatively new for everybody but I wonder wheter some conventions exist about how to design such an MVC application in order to have a flexible and maintainable web application, any guidelines to follow? I am not looking for the 'best' way to do it but for some opinions.

*Note: I deliberately didn't put a lot of code here to not be focus on it but feel free to illustrate your answer with whatever you want (code, schema, links...).*

---

Here is an example of what I am doing. In this example, everything is done in react classes, maybe it's a the best way to do it, maybe not, I need your thoughts.

To sum up, it creates a list of elements (Boostrap list group) from an array given as input (something like [{name: itemName1, type:itemType1}, {name: itemName2, type:itemType2} ...] which generates a view like:

- itemName1
- itemName2
- ...

Each item as its own style according to its type. Then through the input text box, user can make a search trough this list, it filters the list and generates a new one that composed with the matching elements (the search algorithm is not right and will be changed). Plus, there are additional commands with certain keyboard key. Everything works fine but as you can notice, all is in react classes, I don't figure out how to fit Meteor with React.

Meteor file:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Meteor.startup(function() {
    //Build the view
    React.renderComponent(
      <Search items={initialItems}/>,
      document.getElementById('main')
      );
  });
}
```

React file:

```
Search = React.createClass({
    getInitialState : function() {
        return (
            { 
                items : flat(this.props.items),
                active : 0
             }
        );
    },
    setListVisibility: function(visibility) {
        this.refs.list.getDOMNode().style.visibility = visibility;
    },
    onchangeHandler: function() {
        var re = new RegExp(this.refs.search.getDOMNode().value, "i");
        var res = [];
        //filter on props.items and not state.items
        flat(this.props.items).map(function(item){
            if(item.name.search(re) >= 0)
                res.push(item);
        });
        this.setState({ items : res, active : 0});
    }, 
    onkeydownHandler: function(event){
        if(event.key == "ArrowDown" || event.key == "ArrowUp"){
            var shift = event.key == "ArrowDown" ? 1 : -1;
            var newActive = this.state.active + shift;
            if(newActive >= 0 && newActive < this.state.items.length)
                this.setState({ active : this.state.active + shift });
        } else if(event.key == "ArrowRight"){
            if(this.state.items.length > 0){
                var item = this.state.items[this.state.active];
                var newItems = retrieveItem(this.props.items, item.name, typeToSubType[item.type]);
                newItems = flat(newItems);
                if(newItems.length > 0)
                    this.setState({ items : newItems, active : 0 });
            }
        } else if(event.key == "ArrowLeft"){
            this.setState({ items : flat(this.props.items), active : 0});
        } else if(event.key == "Enter"){
            if(this.state.items.length > 0){
                var item = this.state.items[this.state.active];
                console.log("Add "+item.name+" "+item.type+" to the view");
            }
        }
    },  
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                <nav className="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
                    <div className="container-fluid">
                        <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                            <form className="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
                                <div className="form-group">
                                    <input ref="search" type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Search" size="100" 
                                        onChange={this.onchangeHandler} 
                                        onKeyDown={this.onkeydownHandler}
                                        onFocus={this.setListVisibility.bind(this, "visible")}
                                        onBlur={this.setListVisibility.bind(this, "hidden")}/>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
                <List ref="list" items={this.state.items} active={this.state.active}/>
            </div>
            );
    }
});

List = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        var createItem = function(item, index) {
            var cl = "list-group-item";
            if(index == this.props.active)
                cl += " active";

            var gly = "glyphicon ";
            switch(item.type){
                case "dimension":
                    gly += "glyphicon-certificate";
                    break;
                case "hierarchy":
                    gly += "glyphicon-magnet";
                    break;
                case "level":
                    gly += "glyphicon-leaf";
                    break;          
                case "measure":
                    gly += "glyphicon-screenshot";
                    break;
            }

            return (<a href="#" className={cl} key={item.type+"/"+item.name}>
                    <span className={gly}></span>{"   "}{item.name}
                    </a>);
        };
        return (
            <div className="list-group search-list">
                {this.props.items.map(createItem, this)}
            </div>
            );
    }
});
```

Comment: could you post what you've got so far to a public repo?

Comment: I have added a piece of code from my main project in my post. Hope it is readable enough.

Comment: if you can upload a reproduction of the issue to a public repo you may have more luck with getting help.

Comment: In terms of putting the two together, this may help - Peter Hunt, React and Meteor + Functional programming - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qqVbr_LaCIo

Answer (score 7):

Your approach is sound: Meteor for the model and React for the View and ViewController.

Anything functionality that has nothing to do with presentation should be in the model (business logic, validation rules, etc).

Anything to do with presentation and responding to user input should be in React (input, validation output, etc).

Answer (score 2):

Today you could consider this nice peace of code:
https://github.com/reactjs/react-meteor

This repository defines a Meteor package that automatically integrates the React rendering framework on both the client and the server, to complement or replace the default Handlebars templating system.

Comment: Blog post at http://blog.percolatestudio.com/engineering/reactive-user-interfaces/

Answer (score 2):

**As of Meteor 1.3 there is an officially supported way to integrate React with Meteor. So for anyone stumbling across this question today, here's the Meteor 1.3+ answer:**

To use React as Meteor's view layer, first add the React packages from npm:

```
meteor npm install --save react react-dom
```

Now you can simply import React and use it in your project. To render a simple React component, create a simple HTML container:

**client/main.html**

```html
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
</body>
```

And render your React component in it:

**client/main.jsx**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

class HelloWorld extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <p>Hello World!</p>;
  }
}

Meteor.startup(() => {
  render(<HelloWorld />, document.getElementById('app'));
});
```

To use reactive Meteor data sources such as Minimongo collections within React components, you should use the `react-meteor-data` package.

**Read more** in [the official Meteor guide](https://guide.meteor.com/react.html)